# Text direction in apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to make the text direction in Apache poi as Vertical.
I tried Vertical alignment. I am not able to get the desired results.
I don't want to rotate the text.
Something like :

```
T
E
X
T
```

Comment: what are you using? word doc or excel?

Comment: I am creating an Excel sheet using Java library Apache Poi.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a cellStyle, where You have a method setRotation(short rotation). Subsequently apply the cellstyle to Your cell.

docs, for setRotation
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setRotation(short)

Comment: that will rotate the text which is not intended.
anyways I found a solution
I found something on net. A bug which was resolved on the similar issue.

> cellStyle.setRotation(0xff) will do the trick.

Hope it helps anyone who face this problem.

Source:
[http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/DO-NOT-REPLY-Bug-49524-New-add-vertical-text-orientation-method-td2341136.html][1]


  [1]: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/DO-NOT-REPLY-Bug-49524-New-add-vertical-text-orientation-method-td2341136.html

Comment: @Ayush Your solution is correct.  Please post it as an answer; you're allowed and encouraged to answer your own question.

Comment: @rgettman Actually I cant post answers right now. May be cause of some bad questions or queries earlier. Hope this block gets removed soon.