# Apache POI - Vertical Cell Alignment in HSSF Cell Format

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there any way to write a cell with the "Vertical" text orientation available in Apache POI? I can only find a method setRotation that rotates the entire text, rather than have it as Excel displays it when the "Vertical" option is applied. Visually this will look like:

this text

becomes

```
t
h
i
s

t
e
x
t
```

Comment: Duplicate of (non-answered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775688/text-direction-in-apache-poi

Comment: Hmm that didn't show up when I searched.

Comment: Wasn't that useful anyway =)

Comment: Could you read an excel file that has a cell with the proper style and check if the cell style could be copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [HSSFCell.setRotation(short)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setRotation%28short%29)

> set the degree of rotation for the text in the cell
>
> rotation - degrees (between -90 and 90 degrees, or 0xff for vertical)

So, you'll first need to create a (single, workbook-wide) cell style with that on:

```
CellStyle styleVertical = wb.createCellStyle();
styleVertical.setRotation(0xff);
```

Then apply that to your cell

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("this text");
cell.setCellStyle(styleVertical);
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();//where 'wb' is the workbook
cs.setWrapText(true);
cell.setCellStyle(cs);//where 'cell' is the cell you wish to edit
```

After that, the standard `\n` can be used to make a new line in the cell.

Comment: This modifies the value of the cell which usually is not quite desired or encourages to make the cell narrow.  Does create the visually desired end goal though.

Comment: @AleksiYrttiaho good point. But when a user is actually making an Excel cell (in Excel itself) the user has to make new lines if the want to accomplish the same task so this is no different than the way this is done in Excel.

Comment: Excel has the option for vertical text, see screenshot in http://www.mcstech.net/blog/index.cfm/2012/3/19/Excel-Vertical-Text-for-labeling-groups-of-rows. Tested on Office for Mac 2011 and it worked as Greg wants it to work

Comment: So it looks like the answer is no. I wonder if that's a deal breaker for us, the reason I am looking at POI is that jxl produces a strange artefact on OS X versions of Excel when freezing panes.